# Как получить полный путь к папкам Temp и Application Data

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Имеются ввиду системная папка `Temp` в `WINDOWS\` и `Application Data` (`%APPDATA%`)

Comment: Попробуй вот этот вопрос посмотреть
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920853/how-to-open-a-folder-in-appdata-with-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920853/how-to-open-a-folder-in-appdata-with-c][1])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%APPDATA%` можно получить, например, функцией `SHGetFolderPath` или `getenv` из стандартной библиотеки, `%TEMP%` для текущего пользователя - `GetTempPath` или та же `getenv`, а вот для получения системной папки `%TEMP%` придётся использовать функцию `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Userenv.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    char* path;

    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath))) {
        std::cout << "%APPDATA% (SHGetFolderPath) = " << szPath << std::endl;
    }

    path = getenv("APPDATA");
    if (path != NULL) {
        std::cout << "%APPDATA% (getenv) = " << path << std::endl;
    }

    if (GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, szPath)) {
        std::cout << "User's %TEMP% (GetTempPath) = " << szPath << std::endl;
    }

    path = getenv("TEMP");
    if (path != NULL) {
        std::cout << "User's %TEMP% (getenv) = " << path << std::endl;
    }

    if (ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser(NULL, "%TEMP%", szPath, MAX_PATH)) {
        std::cout << "System's %TEMP% = " << szPath << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Для использования `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser` нужно дополнительно прилинковаться к `Userenv.dll`.